# Can Resharper Intellisense be configured to sort alphabetically?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, intellisense, resharper-8.0

I've recently updated to using VS2013 and Resharper 8.2, (from VS2010 and Resharper 6) and have found a very annoying "*feature*" in that Resharper's intellisense does not sort a class's members alphabetically.

By way of example, I have an object called "client" which has a property called **EthnicityRequired**, and another property called **Ethnicities**.

Using only native VS2013 intellisense, this is what I get I type *client.eth*
[image]

This is what I expect; both properties are listed together.

But, Resharper's Intellisense(less) gives me this

[image]

While the visible members are sorted alphabetically, the missing **Ethnicities** property is way down the bottom of the list and will only be matched if I type "*ethnicti*" so that the text no longer matches with **EthnicityRequired**.

From closer inspection of the list, it appears that Resharper is applying some sort of grouping and then sorting  alphabetically within each group.

Does anyone know how to get rid of this rather useless behaviour, and revert to a straight alpha sort like Resharper 6.0 and earlier versions?

Bonus points if you can provide a defence of JetBrains' rationale.

Comment: right-click in the popup

Comment: @ZdravkoDanev Nothing happens. What do you expect to happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the glitch was specific to ReSharper version 8.2.1.  I have just downloaded/installed the latest release, 8.2.3, and the list of members is once again shown in alpha order.[image]

Comment: I am using 9.1.1 and again it is sorting in the wrong order.

Answer (score 9):

In Resharper Ultimate 2016.1 you can do this :

Resharper => Options => IntelliSense => Completion Behavior => Set **Sort Items** to **Alphabetically**

Answer (score 1):

IntelliSense can be reverted to Visual Studio as follows:

Resharper => Options => IntelliSense => General => Custom IntelliSense => set C# to Visual Studio

No sure how much Resharper benefit I'm losing by doing this - but needs must.