# IntelliSense: aria-valuemax and data-ng-style aaaargh?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, resharper, intellisense

While typing code in a Razor (.cshtml) file using Visual Studio 2013 (Update 4) with ReSharper 8.2.3 (updated by suggestion from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26498408/27457)), my IntelliSense is doing stuff that is driving me crazy.  I am a heavy user of the IntelliSense+Tab key when typing to speed up my coding, but some common keywords keep defaulting to suggestions that aren't as intuitive as you'd think.  Examples:

`<input type="whatever" value="something" />` prefers `aria-valuemax` instead of `value`:

[image: aria-valuemax]

`<input type="whatever" style="yada yada" />` prefers `data-ng-style` instead of `style`:

[image: data-ng-style]

I know this is a niggling thing, but it is driving me nuts, and it seems to me that IntelliSense should be preferring `value` and `style` here simply because what I'm typing **does not start with** `aria` and `data` in the respective examples.  Does anyone know how to turn this behavior off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the AngularJS plugin for ReSharper. The latest version is a bit more sane with respect to item ordering and will choose `style` over `data-hg-style`. However, most of this goodness comes from ReSharper itself, and the latest version of the plugin requires ReSharper 9.1.