# is there an "autocomplete" extension for visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio

For visual studio, is there an appropriate extension for the auto-complete window?
By default, all functions and variables are shown in alphabetical order.

[image]

What I want is an extension that separates functions of base classes. 
For example:

- **A_MyLocalFunc()**
- **B_MyOtherLocalFunc()**
- **C_MyLocalFunc()**
- A_baseClasssFunc();
- B_baseClassFunc();
- C_baseClassFunc();

This would simplify the work immensely, because I have a lot of functions in a very popular base class. Sifting through them is no fun

For c++ and c#

Comment: I haven't used [Resharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper) before, but I think you might find something like this there. Here's a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26498408/4934172).

Comment: Static ordering is out of date. See machine learning based ordering https://techcrunch.com/2018/05/07/microsofts-new-intellicode-is-a-smarter-intellisense/